# What is the difference between these using statements of interop in c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I need to generate reports in Word from my c# application. Therefore I am exploring the Interop.Word library. I am now starting to test out how it works and such. But the first thing that I was wondering about was what the difference is between the following two using statments.

The first one is just how I figured I had to include the libraries and I have seen in many examples online:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

The other one I have found on the MDSN [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342218.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), which is the following statement:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Can anyone explain the difference and which one should I use (since they both seem to have the same result).

Comment: the second one uses an alias

Comment: the fact it's interop is irrlevant BTW.

Comment: oh I see from the example of the mdsn page. I suppose it is to make make the code clearer. Because they use "var wordApp = new Word.Application", instead of "var wordApp = new Application". I did not know it was an alias so I could not have known about the question you referenced, but thanks for the link!

Comment: which is fine. Still a dupe though. Dupes are not really a bad thing so don't worry about it.

Comment: alright, thank you for your quick reply.